# Use multiple tables to find a record MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm sorry if the title is missleading, but I didn't know how to sum it up, sorry :(

Basically, I've made a event system that shows events that you can attend. 
I got two tables

"events" and "registrations"
The events table contains all information about a single event, datetime of the event, price,, etc...

Everytime a user clicks register on an event, a record is added to the registration table.
A record looks like this: Registrationid, eventid, date, status and userid

Now I use this query to get all passed events:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE Date < CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY Date ASC
```

I only want it to show previous events on the user page, if the user has actually attended the event. Is there a way I can check the registration table, and if a record exists for that event; show the event? I can do this is php, but I figured it would be possible via MySQL, though I'm not completely sure.

Is there a query that can handle the job? :)

Comment: Ever heard of [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)?

Comment: I have not, sorry, will this do the job? :)

Comment: yup. `JOIN` is what you need. google `mysql join tutorial` for easy understanding.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to maybe give me an example of how I would do this, using the information i provided above? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's a pretty simple join operation. Here's how I would do this:

```
select e.*
from event e join registration r
on (r.event_id=e.event_id)
where r.user_id=123 and e.date < current_date()
order by e.date asc
```

A couple of other tips:

1. Avoid using reserved words and data types as column names (e.g. "date")
2. The default storage engine in MySQL does not support referential integrity. If you need referential integrity, take a peek at InnoDB.

For more on joins in MySQL, check this out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: this seems to be working flawless! Thank you, this definately gave me something to work with ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM events e , registrations r where e.eventid = r.eventid AND e.Date < CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
JOIN registrations r
ON e.eventid = r.eventid
WHERE Date < CURRENT_DATE()
AND r.userid = <insert id here>
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

This query would give you all the fields from the **events** table, where a record in the **registrations** table has a specific user id.

Answer (score 0):

Example Select with a join with your information:

```
SELECT * FROM events AS e WHERE e.Date < CURRENT_DATE() JOIN registration AS r ON e.id = r.eventid ORDER BY e.Date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite other commenters' suggestion to use a `JOIN` (which is a decent suggestion), I think it's actually better in this case to use `IN` plus a subquery:

```
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE eventid IN
        ( SELECT r.eventid
            FROM registrations r
           WHERE r.userid = ...
        )
   AND date < CURRENT_DATE()
 ORDER
    BY date ASC
```

(replacing the `...` with the appropriate user-ID).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `JOIN`, you can select the `registrations` rows for the `userid`, and then get the `events` data

```
SELECT 
    r.*, // Instead of *, you could specify the columns -  r.userid, r.status, etc
    e.* // Instead of *, you could specify the columns - e.event_name, e.Date, etc
FROM 
    registrations r
JOIN 
    events e
ON
    r.eventid = e.id
WHERE
    r.userid = YOUR_USERID
AND
    r.status = ATTENDED
AND
    e.Date < CURRENT_DATE() 
ORDER BY 
    e.Date ASC
```